# ajax checkbox php

Tags: php, ajax, forms, checkbox

I have a php-ajax page that where user writes **search string in  search.php**, and the **list is echoed in getsearch.php**. and the **result of getsearch.php is show in search.php in  using ajax** But there is check box in every row.

```
getsearch.php 

$q = $_GET["q"];

$sql = "select hobbyid,hobby from hobbies where hobby LIKE '%".$q."%' ";

if($result=mysql_query($sql))
{
    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    { 
         $v = $row['hobbyid'];
         echo $row['hobby'] . '<input type="checkbox" name="hobby[]" value='.$v.'>';
    }
}
```

And you can see in following code , this sql is fired for every change(onkeyup). I have kept a check box to get array of selected hobbies. These are selected values are **passed to updatehobby.php.**

```
search.php

echo '<form action="updatehobby.php" method="POST">
echo 'Search:<input type="text"  onkeyup="showSearch(this.value)" />
<div id="txtSearch" >HERE THE RESULTS FROM getsearch.php are shown</div>
<input type="submit></form>';
```

**So when the user writes a new search string, the list gets changed and so the previous check boxes are deselected. So how can i retain the previous check boxes and display them even if the search changes?**

**Ultimately after 1 day trying, I successfully did this way!**

See user enters search string in search.php and the query is passed to getsearch.php and from there the results are echoed and this results are shown in search.php

So instead of using check box, i inserted a button. So every row now has a button instead of 
checkbox.

```
<button type="button" onClick="submitform(<?php echo $row['hobbyid']; ?     >);">Add hobby</button>
```

Now in search.php i again used another ajax function (submitform) which handled the onclick call of button.
When the button add hobby is pressed, ajax function submitform is called and the hobby is inserted.

**So basically i used two ajax functions in search.php , one ajax for searching and populating results and another for updating it to database.**

Comment: You have a XSS and SQL injection problem in your code, dont insert user provided input unescaped in a sql query, dont output unescaped content from your database.

Comment: ya i removed many codes which were not useful for the question....it was making the code look too complex...

Comment: @netdeamon you have used two *JavaScript* functions. *AJAX* is a technology which allows you to send requests to server without reloading whole page.

Comment: But my page is never reloaded, and it is ajax that i have used. When the user clicks in add button, the button gets removed and "added" is displayed. Also that row is displayed even if the query changes.When the user adds a  hobby, I store it in SESSION['recently_added'], and in sql query I pass this SESSION variable also,so the row is always displayed. I haven't used javascript!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) You may send checkboxes state in your search request and set checked/not checked in PHP code and include it in your request to database so it will be like

`"select hobbyid,hobby from hobbies
 where hobby LIKE '%".$q."%' or hobbyid in(list_of_hobbies_received_in_request) "`

than, in your loop where you render an HTML - check if id is in received array of ids and set checked state for required hobbies.

(2) Or you can remeber checkboxes state before you send request in javascript and after response came - avoid deleting selected checkboxes and check that there is no duplicates.   But it looks like that will be a big pain with how you are getting search results. So, I think (1) is what you need.

Comment: means I use javascript code in getsearch.php and store the checked ones in an array...right?

Comment: yes. So code will be like this: `function showSearch() { collectCheckboxes() ...}` and in your success callback hadnler just restore it.

Comment: But suppose you need to gput some ids on your checkboxes and use them to restore selection state. But as for me - it would be better to set checked/not checked state on server. Because on client you may get some delay between new HTML is rendered and checkboxes checked back

Comment: oh means I will remove the submit button in search.php and will put submit button for each row and will use that to insert hobby into database. like in if(server_request==post) then { insert the submitted value in database}....the problem of checkbox will be eliminated...am i right?

Comment: Hm. Suppose you need to specify why do you need those checkboxes. I understand your question like user may check some rows and than update search string. After it is updated - you want to show previously selected checkboxes if row is still in search result. Or that is wrong?

Comment: Yeh i finally did this as you said, i have updated the code in question..thanks FAngel.

Comment: Sorry, you did not as I said. I'm afraid you need to learn something first. People say that codeacademy is good for this. It looks to me that I need to write a code for you if I want you to get that working. But I see no reason to do that and suppose nobody will spend his time to do your job.